# Unable to upgrade Ubuntu from 20.10 to 21.04

Tags: upgrade, python3, 20.10

I can't upgrade Ubuntu from 20.10 to 21.04: after launching `update-manager -c` I constantly see strange error:

> Your python3 install is corrupted. Please fix the '/usr/bin/python3' symlink.

Anyone have any idea why this happens? I remove all alternatives for `python` and `python3` already. `/usr/bin/python3` links to `/etc/alternatives/python3`, and last one links to `/usr/bin/python3.8`. Analogously `/usr/bin/python` links to `/etc/alternatives/python`, and last one links to `/usr/bin/python2.7`.

Comment: Maybe reinstall python3 package?

Comment: Why would there be any link to python2.7?  Releases later than 19.10 do **not** include any references to python2 as it's EOL so I'm guessing you haven't restored the links back to default.   (*if you added python2; links to it will only be from python2 you don't mention*)

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz already tried

Comment: @guiverc Before python symlinks linked to `/usr/bin/python3.8`, I've just tried another possibility) Anyway, it doesn't work